# Mechanical Turk without Masters (Categorization on Sandbox)

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm trying to test out my HIT on Mechanical Turk Sandbox with the categorization layout.

Everything works fine and I can deploy my HIT, except that I'm unable to figure out how to remove the requirement that workers must be Masters to participate.

Thus I am unable to complete the HIT through the Worker Sandbox because my account doesn't have a Masters qualification. I tried applying for the Masters qualification to no avail (and unsurprisingly so). I've found quite a few workarounds to removing the Masters qualification that were posted about back in 2011-2013 period, but it seems that Amazon has quite significantly changed the webpage since then.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, or if there is another way for me to try out my own HIT on Sandbox.

Comment: If you use the built-in "projects" provided by Amazon, they come with non-removable qualification requirements. You can build the exact same thing from scratch yourself, but you just have to not choose the "categorization project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas' answer is the correct answer. If you create a Project using the Requester Website (http://requester.mturk.com/) and select either of "Sentiment" or "Categorization" template then it chooses Masters and there is no way of disabling it. It's worth noting that even though I describe these as "templates" they are in fact considered "applications" -- that is, they are designed to remove a lot of the complexity and "heavy lifting" that a Requester would normally do. That includes making approvals simpler (the "application" will take care of reviews and approvals), making pricing easier (the "application" will help recommend pricing based on marketplace conditions), and Worker quality (this is where Masters are selected by default and are non-optional).

Thomas' suggestion is to create your own template for MTurk Categorization (or Sentiment Analysis). This is probably the best suggestion. Check out "Tagging of an Image" for a template that you could quickly rework (assuming your categorization is of an image). You'll want to convert the three text inputs into a dropdown that includes your categorization. If you need to get more fancy (multi-level categorization) you can check out some fancy instantiations of it at sites like this:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Sorry, as I'm sure that's not the answer you wanted to hear. But hope that helps lessen some of the time you're no-doubt spending to investigate this.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this! I will try using the tagging of an image template.